Why is the index of a pallet a u32(usize) instead of u8 when queried?
I'm implementing a flow where I first ask what index a pallet has with the QueryPallet xcm instruction, and then construct a call to use with Transact.
I see that to construct manually an encoded call to place inside Transact I need to put as the first byte, the pallet index, and second byte the call index. But the item returned by QueryPallet is PalletInfo which has the index field as a u32, not u8. So I'm not sure how to handle the case where the index cannot convert to u8.
I understand that PalletInfo has u32 for the index because when calling for example Balances::index() it returns a u32, not u8. But why is this the case? why define the index as usize instead of the original type, u8?
I also thought it might be because the first byte of a call is a compact u32, such that a u8 or u32, when compacted would be the same encoded binary, but no.
